# Destroying a class object stored as a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dll

I have a following problem. I have a base class which is like an interface and I have a derived class which serve as an actual implementation. Both have virtual function and virtual destructor.

Now I create a pointer to the derived class thru the base one in a DLL and then this pointer is passed back to the main application where its casted implicitly to "void *". When the application ends, the pointer is destroyed by calling delete on the pointer.

Unfortunately deleting a void pointer is an undefined behavior and it is never hits any of the destructors (neither base nor derived) and results in a memory leak. So I tried to cast it - unfortunately that results in a crash.

The current design of the application is as follows:

- Static DLL -> base class
- Dynamic DLL -> derived class
- Dynamic DLL -> where the pointer is created
- Main app -> where the memory should be removed.

The idea is to have main application not to depend (link) on the Static DLL, but only load the dynamic DLL with implementation as needed.

Now in order to fix all this I see 2 ways:

1. Put the base class inside the main application, because main application should manage the pointer and send it anywhere around my app. Then the derived class will be derived from the class exported from the main application.

Question: Can I successfully export a class from the main application and not from DLL? The application is cross-platform, so I will need to do that in Windows, Linux and Mac.

2. Make static DLL dynamic DLL. Then hopefully I will be able to delete the void pointer by proper casting.

So my question is: which one is preferable way? Or maybe there is another, third, way of fixing the memory leak.crash.

Hopefully I explained my situation clearly.

---

***EDIT***: This is my current design:

Static Library - .dll/.a:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual Foo();
};
```

Dynamic Library 1 - .dll/.so:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    virtual Derived1();
    virtual Foo();
};
```

Dynamic Library 2 - .dll/.so:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2();
    virtual ~Derived2();
    virtual Foo();
};
```

Both those library link with the static one as they depend on it.

Dynamic Library 0 - .dll/.so:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Base *Bar()
{
    Base *pb;
    if( <condition1> )
        pb = new Derived1();
    if( <condition2> )
        pb = new Derived2();
    return pb;
}
```

This library link only to dll1 and dll2. They don't need anything from static library.

Main application:

```
class MainFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame();
    ~MainFrame();
    void Baz();
private:
    void *m_pBase;
};

void MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{
    delete m_pBase;
    m_pBase = NULL;
}

void MainFrame::Baz()
{
    // load the library "Dynamic Library 0"
    // get the function pointer
    m_pBase = func();
}
```

Therefore main application don't link to anything - there is no dependency. Only dynamic loading of dll0 is used. And dll0 is creating the object of an appropriate type.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there are lots of parts that didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @xvan, do you know if it is possible to export a class from the main application and NOT from DLL/so cross-platform?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean by export. It looks like a plugin/addon scenario. If all your dll's aren't available at linking time, and don't share a common base/interface, i'd make wrappers that link to the dll, but have a known interface. Void pointers are not needed.

Comment: @xvan, Can you put some pseudo-code? I'm not sure what you mean. Thx in advance. BTW, by saying "export" I mean that the code is using "__declspec(dllexport)".

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) is windows only. What i mean is [interface class (all methods pure virtual)], [wrapper pimpl class (implements the interface, wraps your static dll)], on main, you just import your dynamic dll, construct your wrapper and cast it to the interface. No void pointer required. Each wrapper just exports its interface, one dll per wrapper.

Comment: @xvan, could you put some code for me to see? Because if I do this: "MyInterface *pInterface = new Derived1;" I will need to have "MyInterface" pointer stored somewhere. Which means I will have to link to the interface static library. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @xvan, also, please see my edit. I put in my design for you. There is no pure virtuals anywhere. Trouble is - when I close the application I get a memory leak, since m_pBase is void and the execution does not destroy the Derived/Base objects. So could you show me what do you have in mind?

Comment: m_pBase is `Base *`, not `void *`. MainFrame dll should know of Base interface type. That's what interfaces are for. Also base is pure virtual, so it's just a header, not a lib.

Comment: @xvan, so basically all I need to change is make all Base functions pure virtual and change the "void *" to become "Base *", right? The Base class will still be inside .dll/.so, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Base class is pure virtual, no constructor, no member variables, all virtual methods `=0`. As there is no implementation, there is no lib, it's just a header.

Comment: @xvan, yes, I understand that. What I mean is that it can be located in its own project which will be compiled in the dll/so, right? I just don't want to copy the same header to n different project (dll/so/dylib).

Answer (score 0):

Provide it as a pointer to your base class, and declare the destructor as virtual.

Comment: then the main application will link to the static library, which I'd like to avoid. Is it possible to export a class from the main app?

Comment: @Igor I don't understand the question.